# Qt Signals/Slots Changeable?

Tags: c++, qt

I have been writing some basic applications with Qt, and have found its signals and slots mechanism to be very helpful.  However, there is something I am hoping to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Basically, I want to have a screen with some text, pictures, whatever and a block of buttons. When I push a button, I want the other stuff on screen to change accordingly.  Then I want to repeat the process.  The application I am thinking of works similar to a basic text-based game.

I am hoping to write something like this:

```
void someFunction()
{
    //Display some stuff
    if(button1pressed())
    {
        //display some different stuff
        if(button1pressed())
        {
             ...
        }
        if(button2pressed())
        {
            ...
        }
        if(button...pressed())
        {
           ...
        }
    }
    if(button2pressed())
    {
        //display some different stuff
        if(button1pressed())
        {
             ...
        }
        if(button2pressed())
        {
            ...
        }
        if(button...pressed())
        {
           ...
        }
   }
    if(button...pressed())
    {
        //display some different stuff
        if(button1pressed())
        {
             ...
        }
        if(button2pressed())
        {
            ...
        }
        if(button...pressed())
        {
           ...
        }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to nest button presses like this? Or another way to accomplish the same idea? Thanks!

Comment: If you want some gui element that save state after user click, why not just use `QRadioButton` or `QCheckBox`? They have something like ` isChecked`

Comment: Would I then loop over each part, checking until one is pressed?  I will look into this further.

Comment: No, loops of course possible, but this is `no go` in terms of modern computer usage (to prevent battery eating for example), change your design to be event based

Comment: I have been trying to come up with a way to do this event based instead of looping to wait on user input, but I haven't thought of a way yet.  Do you have any suggestions?
The only thing I have thought of would be to make new buttons/checkboxes for each "level" of nesting instead of reusing the same ones, but that would probably result in thousands of buttons/boxes to try to keep track of, which doesn't seem like a good solution either.

Comment: write for each level `class LevelX` with suitable slots, and maintains the state of your level inside `class LevelX`, not in buttons. For new level use `disconnect` and `connect`.

Comment: Hmm, that seems like a good possibility.  It would require a lot of classes, but it would prevent the looping... Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Next step will be create one `Level` class, that load LevelX config from file, and manage its current state according to this config.

Comment: I have never done anything like that before. You wouldn't happen know of a good example for switching classes like that, would you?

Answer (score 3):

Too much nested "if" statements is not a good idea. For the readability of the code, and for the future if you want to update your software. This is always simple at the beginning but it tends to be complicated then... You can use the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) which allows you to change the behavior of a object depending on actions taken. Each call of a button will change the internal state of an object, and the way this change is done can depend on the current internal state. For example:

- Initial state is "1"
- From state "1", triggering button "A" leads to the state "2"
- From state "2", triggering button "A" leads to the state "3"
- From state "3", triggering button "B" reinitializes to the state "1"

Edit: as stated by Kuba, [QStateMachine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatemachine.html) is a class helping you in this process.

Another idea would be to store the order of the buttons pressed. Connect each press event to a slot ([QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) can help), and store the order in a list. Then process the list and do actions accordingly.